# For com DateTime em Razor dando out of memory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

Estou tendo o erro out of memory, sendo ele causado por esse codigo Razor no meu arquivo cshtml, e não consigo identificar onde está o problema.

```
@for(DateTime data = DateTime.Today.Date; data <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(7).Date; data.AddDays(1))
{
    @data
}
```

Comment: Acho improvável, o problema deve estar em outro lugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação, o método [`DateTime.AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> **Retorna** um novo `DateTime` que adiciona o número especificado de dias ao valor dessa instância.

Perceba a ênfase. Esse método **retorna** o resultado, e não modifica a instância. Por isso, sua variável `data` nunca está sendo modificada, gerando um *loop* infinito e, consequentemente, a exceção *OutOfMemory*.

Para resolver, basta sobrescrever `data` com o valor de retorno do método

```
@for(DateTime data = DateTime.Today.Date; data <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(7).Date; data = data.AddDays(1))
{
    @data
}
```

<sub>[Veja funcionando no .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qHlGq1)</sub>